# How to add widgets to main screen after footer selection

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im trying to make a flutter showcase app for tutorial purposes but I just can't get to add widgets into it after clicking an footer item no matter what I have tried I have failed so im seeking the help of those who know what they are doing will people of the fascinating forum help a newbie to become a programmer ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
  TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
   Text(
     'Index 0: Home',
     style: optionStyle,
   ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter showcase'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(null),
            label: 'Butonlar',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(null),
            label: 'TextBox lar',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(null),
            label: 'ComboBoxlar',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

to be more precise I want to replace

```
 Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
```

with a widget thanks in advance you guys really help a lot!

Comment: I can't understand your problem. Can you add sample code trying what do you want? (Do you want to change the content of _widgetOptions[index] ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what I could understand of your problem, what I did was to add widgets to the index 0 and 1 of the variable _widgetOptions  and remove the const keyboard from it , is better to import these widget from another file in order to have a better organization.

Here the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[500],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[100],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
    ),
  ],
),
   Image.network('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg'),
    const Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```